# Is there a way to perform Rolling Update of two dependent deployments?

Tags: kubernetes

I have two deployment in one service:
First deployment is application backend;
Second deployment is a LDAP that stores configuration for backend;

I want to initalize LDAP then backend and only after that perform rolling update for both deployments.

I understand that i can use Init Containers and Readness probes if i want to wait a new deployment to initialize before update, but how can i achive the same for two deployments?

Answer (score 2):

You may use initContainer for LDAP which initializes it, then start LDAP. Also you may use initContainer in your backend app which waits for LDAP service to become available. This way your backend will always wait for LDAP initialization. This is a common practice for creating application dependencies in Kube world.